# How was the "pen through the lip" scene shot?

Tags: film-techniques, red-lights

In the film 'Red Lights' (2012), how did Cillian Murphy's character stick a pen through his lower lip? It wasn't real, was it?

I can't find anything on google that that even mentions it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this interview](http://arts.nationalpost.com/2012/08/07/rodrigo-cortes-and-cillian-murphy-debunk-paranormal-phenomena-in-red-lights/) with the director Rodrigo Cortés, it's an illusion Murphy actually performs:

> After Murphy was cast, the actor hung out with a magician in Cortés’s native Spain and watched David Copperfield and Criss Angel’s shows in Las Vegas. Murphy learned a few tricks along the way, all of which he performs in the film, including a “stabbing” illusion, in which Murphy places a pen through his lip.

So how is this trick done? Well, at the risk of getting kicked out of the Magicians' Alliance, I'm guessing it's the same as "pen through a dollar": It's actually a **trick pen** that comes apart and is held together with **magnets**; this fact is then obscured by slight of hand. You can see the trick explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrAkh4r48DY) and done on a lip [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVonkaAitR8) (presumably with strong magnets that [work through flesh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LV-CVaUBOk8) instead of paper). Note how he obscures the pen during the actual 'stabbing' and that afterwards, we don't see any part of the pen really *sliding through* the 'hole', it's just stuck there. There can also be a *real* pen hidden in the other end if you need to write with it first; this is also explained in the first clip.